# Example creating a MF-USG model in flopy

Tags: flopy

I am interested in creating a MF-USG model in flopy with a quadtree grid. I have created the disu using gridgen, but now I am stuck on how to assign properties and boundaries to the model, as the all examples of unstructured grids I can find are for MF6.

This is where I am at...

m = flopy.modflow.Modflow(model_name = model_name,version = "mfusg",structured=False,model_ws=model_ws)

m.dis = g.get_disu(m,nper = 1,perlen=1000,nstp = 100,tsmult=1.2,steady = False)

Can anyone point me to an example of building a MF-USG model with properties and BCs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Packages of MODFLOW-USG that flopy supports are DISU and SMS
[See the Git-Hud FloPy Supported Packages page](https://github.com/modflowpy/flopy/blob/develop/docs/supported_packages.md)

I guess it will be hard if not impossible to find a fully MODFLOW-USG oriented example with flopy.

Changing to MODFLOW-6 might be a better alternative, specially now that it supports groundwater transport, subsidence and density driven flow sharing most of the theory behind.